# I am having problem while running flutter application. error specifies "Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'"

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project in a team and I am getting this problem from 2 days after I update flutter plugins on ide and tried to run it, need help.[image with error message while I am trying to run it on debug mood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rusV5.png)

Comment: This Causes Flutter SDK version mis match check your team mate version and if needed updagrade/dowgrade your SDK .

Comment: @Tasnuvaoshin I tried that and now I am getting 
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter sdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1